# Adding yeast for bottle carbonation

Tags: yeast, cider, bottle-conditioning

I have made 3 batches of cider (two 3-gallon and one 5-gallon) this year and now it is clear and ready. It was racked twice, so now it has no sediment (and possibly no yeast). I was at first planning to force carbonate it in a keg, but honestly, I prefer bottle carbonated ciders.

I am planning to use either DV-10 or EC-1118 (both are champagne yeasts and both good for cider). I am planning to add yeast to a bucket, transfer cider to that bucket, slowly stirring. I also plan to use 1/2 lbs of corn sugar as a primer for 1 batch, and carbonation drops for the second batch. I'll be using champagne and Belgian bottles with corks and cages.

What would be the best way to prepare yeast? 
Should I make a starter with a juice or should I hydrate the yeast with GoFerm? 
How much should I use, like 5 grams for 3 gallons, 8 grams for 5 gallons?

Comment: General hint is never do starter from fresh dry yeast. It's hard to get better cell count than in the package. But I don't know the yeast you mentioned, so hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a starter for dry yeast.  Also, the amount of sugar you plan to use is way over the top.  For highly carbed cider, I use 1 oz. of sugar per gallon of cider.